# ASDM - ASA Issue

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa

This is actually a two part question, if anyone has had experience with the issue and could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Backstory: Using GNS3 with ASA 8.4(2) and ASDM 7.1(5).  I've successfully setup the ASA in GNS3 under qemu and I can console into the ASA just fine and run commands; however, I'm having a terrible issue with ASDM.

Issues: First issue is I can't run the ASDM launcher directly from my desktop which is connected via a loopback adapter in GNS (Cloud), it just stays at the connecting screen.  Second issue is, I *can* reach the ASA via ASDM using the java applet.  All areas appear to be working except when I click on interfaces it waits for a while and then times out.  I see in the ASDM logger that it's giving this error: ASA-1-199010: Signal 11 caught in process/fiber.

Has anyone had these issues using ASA/ASDM in GNS3?  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Does SSH access work properly?

Comment: Yes it does.  All the basic configuration is there.

Comment: How's the performance on it running within the emulator? Seeing references to that error being caused by lack of resources.

Comment: Its on a pretty descent machine, 8 core, 8 gigs of RAM, etc... It's not sluggish via the console.  Or in any other place in ASDM, just the interface section.  I could definitely be due to performance, but I've double checked full duplex running at 100mbps, and I can't seem to pin it down.  The weird thing is if I let it sit there for about 10 minutes it'll finally show up.